# looping for a sum versus summing a list comprehension

Tags: python

In the sort of calculations I do, I often encounter the need to sum some expression over (at least) one list.  Let's say I want to find the sum of x^2 for x in some list L.  Is there a significant difference between run times of

```
sum([val**2 for val in L])
```

versus

```
total = 0
for val in L:
    total+=val**2
```

and would this change if I had a more complicated expression to sum?  I'm not concerned about the memory issues associated with creating a list, but cleaner code and faster run time matter.

I'm basically wondering whether the optimization that people have probability done to list generators and to sum would get me a faster code - doing the loop in C rather than python.

**edit** for anyone searching for this, the answer turns out to be that converting to numpy arrays and then doing the calculation is fastest of all.

Comment: `Is there a significant difference between run times of ...` - No, they both run in linear time. Also, you can avoid the temporary list creation and pass a generator expression, `sum(val**2 for val in L)`

Comment: Not an answer, but the first one looks cleaner and it takes less code.

Comment: @thefourtheye  I realize that, but a 30% speed up would be noticeable.

Comment: @Joel `30%`? How did you come up with that number?

Comment: @thefourtheye: He's asking if one is actually faster in real time, not in asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @thefourtheye : I chose the number arbitrarily.  I'll edit the question slightly to clarify my question.

Comment: You could find out yourself using Python's `timeit` module. :-)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure  Indeed, but I'm also hoping to get some insight into what's going on under the hood since there are tradeoffs.  Also people may have other suggestions that are even better.

Comment: The difference is going to be small compared with the speedup of using numpy.  A few quick tests suggests you may get about a 5% difference between your options, whereas numpy is 10 times faster.

Comment: If you want speed for numeric operations use ```numpy```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most certain answer to do is just test it:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

L = range(1000)
M = np.arange(1000)

def f0():
    sum([val**2 for val in L])

def f1():
    total = 0
    for val in L:
        total+=val**2    

def f2():
    np.sum(M*M)

print timeit.timeit("f0()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, L, M", number=100)
print timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, L, M", number=100)
print timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, L, M", number=100)

# 0.015289068222
# 0.00959897041321
# 0.000958919525146
```

The times have a similar ratio if 1M is used instead of 1K (here I also used `number=10` so I didn't have to wait):

```
# 1.21456193924
# 1.08847117424
# 0.0474879741669
```

That is, the two pure Python approaches are about the same, and using numpy speeds up the calculation 10-20x.

Comment: thanks.  I hadn't thought to convert to numpy - i figured the cost of conversion would lose out.  I tested that in more detail in another answer I posted.  If you can add that to your answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Joel: if you're using numpy for this single calculation, you might want to consider using numpy all the way through. If you have big lists of uniform type, numpy will probably be advantageous for more reasons than this single step: more memory efficient, faster, cleaner syntax, multidimensional, io, etc.

Comment: these are lists of variable size, and the lists can actually change size during the simulations.

Answer (score 0):

Following tom's answer, I wanted to include the cost of creating the np array, and do a fairer comparison where I might be iterating over 2 loops.  So I'm summing x*y over two lists here.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

X = range(10000)
Y = range(10000)
M = np.arange(10000)
N = np.arange(10000)

def f0():
    sum([x*y for x in X for y in Y])

def f1():
    sum(x*y for x in X for y in Y)

def f2():
    total = 0
    for x in X:
        for y in Y:
            total += x*y

def f3():
    np.sum(np.array(X)*np.array(Y))

def f4():
    np.sum(M*N)



print timeit.timeit("f0()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, X, Y, M, N", number=10)
print timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, X, Y, M, N", number=10)
print timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, X, Y, M, N", number=10)
print timeit.timeit("f3()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, X, Y, M, N", number=10)
print timeit.timeit("f4()", setup="from __main__ import f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, X, Y, M, N", number=10)

#73.9396169186
#68.8783578873
#61.4824860096
#0.00859999656677
#0.000278949737549
```

So the answer is list comprehension slowest by about 15-20 percent compared to the loop in Python.

If we have it in numpy already, that's about 30 times faster than the time it would take to create the numpy arrays.  Creating the numpy arrays and doing it in numpy beats out pure python by orders of magnitude - that surprised me.  I guess it shouldn't have.